# Some emacs desktop-save questions: how to change it to save in ~/.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I have this set in my init.el

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

This works great, only I was wondering:

- how can I change it to save the .emacs.desktop files into ~/.emacs.d instead of ~/
- how can I stop it from asking me if I want to save (only occurs the first time I close emacs after a reboot, from then on it assumes yes, which is what I always want to happen)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I use the following, which works for me:

```
;; Automatically save and restore sessions
(setq desktop-dirname             "~/.emacs.d/desktop/"
      desktop-base-file-name      "emacs.desktop"
      desktop-base-lock-name      "lock"
      desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
      desktop-save                t
      desktop-files-not-to-save   "^$" ;reload tramp paths
      desktop-load-locked-desktop nil
      desktop-auto-save-timeout   30)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Well, I actually set `(desktop-save-mode 0)` and then use `M-x my-desktop` to kick things off:

```
(defun my-desktop ()
  "Load the desktop and enable autosaving"
  (interactive)
  (let ((desktop-load-locked-desktop "ask"))
    (desktop-read)
    (desktop-save-mode 1)))
```

But that's because my session is frequently in excess of 100 files, mostly via tramp, and so I prefer to make loading it a manual task, and not clobber the desktop file otherwise :)

I recommend checking out the Emacs Wiki:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop

There are some useful enhancements to the default functionality. In particular, I recommend adding some method of auto-saving your desktop mid-session, as it's *really* annoying if your system crashes when Emacs has been running for several days, and your desktop hasn't been saved in the interim.

Since Emacs 24.4 the desktop file is auto-saved periodically by default. See the `desktop-auto-save-timeout` variable (which I've also added to the block above). Thanks to GDP2 and Dexter Morgan for their comments on this.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir :) Works fantastically. Two additions I made: (could you just tell me if they are obviously wrong?) desktop-files-not-to-save   "*magit" ;ignore magit files, and also (add-hook 'auto-save-hook (lambda () (desktop-save-in-desktop-dir)))

Comment: The auto-save hook looks fine. `desktop-files-not-to-save` needs to be a regular expression, so that looks wrong. If you're matching things ending in "magit" then use `".*magit$"`

Comment: Due to this answer's age, it seems that the last paragraph is no longer accurate. As of at least Emacs 25.1.1, enabling `desktop-save-mode` sets an idle timer that calls `desktop-auto-save` every 5 secs.

Comment: in Emacs 25, setting the variable `desktop-auto-save-timeout` to **n** seconds will make sure a desktop file is saved every **n** seconds. E.g. `(setq desktop-auto-save-timeout 15)`. The default is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I change it to save the
>   .emacs.desktop files into ~/.emacs.d
>   instead of ~/

Customize `desktop-dirname` variable.

> how can I stop it from asking me if I
>   want to save

Customize `desktop-save` variable.

Comment: Cheers for that, I tried adding this with no luck: (desktop-save-mode t)
(setq desktop-dirname "~/.emacs.d/")

Comment: @tobeannounced: `customize` is *not* equivalent to `setq`. Read the help for the variables.

Comment: setting desktop-dirname seems to be insufficient; I couldn't get it to work until I _also_ changed desktop-path :/ self.herp_derp()

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share how my sessions are organized.

Requirements:

1. Send file from terminal to custom emacs session
2. Restore session from terminal
3. Save session

Solution:

1. Install package(plugin) workgroups2 -> https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2
2. Add following lisp code to your ~/.emacs.d/init.el or ~/.emacs:

->

```
(setq server-socket-dir "~/.emacs-local/server")

(defun nk-server-start (custom-server)
    ; (nk-server-start "abe")
    (setq server-name custom-server)
    (server-start) ; run emacs server
    (setq wg-session-file (concat "~/.emacs-local/sessions/" custom-server))
    ; (setq wg-session-file "~/.emacs-local/sessions/foo")
    (workgroups-mode 1)
    (wg-switch-to-workgroup custom-server)
    )
; Run file in specific server (foo)
    ; emacsclient -n callback.sh -s ~/.emacs-local/server/foo

; Show server name in title bar
(setq frame-title-format '("" "%b @ " server-name))
    ; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameTitle

; ;; What to do on Emacs exit / workgroups-mode exit?
(setq wg-emacs-exit-save-behavior           'save)      ; Options: 'save 'ask nil
(setq wg-workgroups-mode-exit-save-behavior 'save)      ; Options: 'save 'ask nil
```

Function `nk-server-start` is called when emacs is started.
It has one argument - sesssion name.

We can start emacs-session `foo` by running following command from terminal:

```
setsid emacs --eval '(nk-server-start "foo")' &
```

If we want to open file in session `foo` from terminal we need to run:

```
setsid emacsclient -n -s ~/.emacs-local/server/foo file.txt >> /dev/null &
```

When we close session, all buffers,settings, etc. are saved in file `~/.emacs-local/sessions/foo`

When we run command `setsid emacs --eval '(nk-server-start "foo")' &` next time, all buffers will be restored

Because commands are large and I am lazy :) I made some scripts and added them to my `$PATH` in order to ease this:

`em_start_foo.sh` - Run session, used only once to start session

```
#!/bin/bash

setsid emacs --eval '(nk-server-start "foo")' &
```

`em_foo.sh` - Add files to session

```
#!/bin/bash

setsid emacsclient -n -s ~/.emacs-local/server/foo "$@" >> /dev/null &
```

Now we just run from terminal:

```
$ em_start_foo.sh                 # start foo session
$ em_foo.sh file_1.txt            # open file_1.txt in foo session
$ em_foo.sh file_2.txt file_3.txt # open file_2.txt and file_3.txt in foo session
```

Multiple sessions can be run in parallel of course.

Let's say we created also scripts `em_start_foo_2.sh`, `em_start_foo_2.sh`, `em_start_foo_3.sh`, `em_start_foo_3.sh` (somewhere in `$PATH` of course)

Then we can do something like this:

```
$ em_start_foo.sh          # start foo session
$ em_start_foo_2.sh        # start foo_2 session in separate emacs
$ em_foo.sh file_1.txt     # open file_1.txt in foo session
$ em_foo_2.sh a.txt b.txt  # open a.txt and b.txt in foo_2 session

$ em_start_foo_3.sh        # start foo_3 session
$ em_foo_3.sh tmp.txt      # open tmp.txt in foo_3 session

##### Close emacs foo_2 from gui - session is automatically saved ###

$ em_start_foo_2.sh        # start foo_2 session with all buffers restored
```

Package `workgroups2` is really great!

My emacs init file with session options is available at: https://github.com/nexayq/dot_files/blob/master/emacs/dot_emacs_d/init.el